# Responding to prefix (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot respond to a prefix. I just can't get it to do so. I've tried all I (currently) know.
*My code:*

```
@client.event
async def on_ready(ctx):
client.when_mentioned(ctx.send='My prefix is `ja`')
```

Comment: Please show us more the methods you tried and the corresponding outputs that you got. Please also include an input and an expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an `on_message` event that checks if the bot user is in the mentions of the message

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    if bot.user in message.mentions: 
        await message.channel.send("My prefix is `ja`")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```